# Openssl fips fingerprint mismatch

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, openssl, fips

I am trying to compile fips validated Openssl lib for iOS. I went through the build process in user guide (which is dated).

1. Build incore_macho
2. Build fipscanister.o
3. Build fips compatible library libcrypto.a and libssl.a

The library was compiled without error. But when I launch the demo app (fips-pi) and try to enter fips mode via

```
FIPS_mode_set(1 /*on*/);
```

It returns error code 755413103, which means the fingerprint does not match. I can also see that the calculated and embedded fingerprint are different on the app itself.

[image]

I am not sure if it is related to the fact that I used clang to compile the lib.

Any suggestions? Thank you!

Edit:

Thank you for the comment @jww. I have the following files under `usr/local/ssl/Release-iphoneos/lib/` (it is the default directory in the user guide)

The section(Appendix E) in the user guide seem out of date and I have to modify the `make` file to meet current dev environment. The way I did:

1. change CC to “CC= $(CROSS_COMPILE)clang” (llvm-gcc no longer exists on OS X)
2. change CROSS_COMPILE to “CROSS_COMPILE = "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/“.

I know this may break fips compliance, but it seems the build progress in the user guide is only prepared for iOS6/armv7 and not longer valid for current environment. Does Openssl have any plan to update the fips user guide for iOS? Otherwise no one knows how to compile the lib as well as maintain fips compliance :)

[image: File list]

Comment: Two questions. (1) what does an `ls` of the cross-compiled `openssl/lib/` directory return? (2) What is the shell command for the post-build script for the target? (By the way, I wrote that particular section of the manual and the fips-pi program to dump the values for testing. But its been a while :)

Comment: Thanks @jww I have modified my question.

Comment: @Summer did you find the answer to this? Getting the same error

Comment: @jww Did that edit ring any bells?